# How does one grant authenticated website users (App Engine standard) access to Google Cloud Storage bucket?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-signin

I've deployed a java8 web application on Google App Engine standard. Currently I have Oauth2 integration, I'm able to get the users email address, token_id etc. The user sign up flow is very standard (even with Oauth2). It's basically get the user to either add their email/password or sign them up using Google sign-in. 
   I have directories and files in Google Cloud Storage that I want to allow "authenticated" users to access. 
Which means:

- a) If their username/password matches what I have in the mysql db 
      or
- b) If I find their google sign in credentials in the db

I redirect them to the servlet that presents all the files in a secure webpage in the form of links where the user can click/open the documents. 
   I'm clear on how to request authorizations on Google resources a user may own. What I need to know is how do I "grant" a user (Google user or regular user that registers on the site) access to files in the Google Cloud Storage bucket?

Unless I grant Storage Object Reader to "allusers" I get:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied.</Message>
<Details>
Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to drmath.appspot.com/1a/index.html.
</Details>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google OAuth is not a solution for your requirements in granting access to Google Cloud Storage. Their email address (User Identity) would need to be added as a user to your Google Cloud IAM.

What you can do is generate signed urls. These are URLs with temporary access that times out. Your backend server code would generate the URL and the user can then directly access the Cloud Storage object for a temporary time.

Your backend would determine that a user is authorized by whatever method you want including using OAuth, database, etc.

[Generating Signed URLs with Your Own Program](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually)

[Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)

Comment: Let me ask this - can I grant the application the privilege to view. In other words I'll just use user sessions to secure the page but when the application accesses Google Cloud Storage it displays the files? What I don't like about the signed url's is: " Anyone in possession of the URL has the access granted by the URL"

Comment: There is no concept of `application` when granting access to Cloud Storage. You either have credentials (User or Service Account) or you have signed urls (which are derived from credentials). To grant `view` to  anything requires an IAM account in Google Cloud.

Comment: I added my email and granted the following:

Comment: Sorry I got distracted with other posts - the url gets tokenized when you add the security to the bucket so I'm thinking this is not going to work, that's what gave me pause in completing my comment. Which also seems to mean the signed urls won't work either. I need the integrity of the structure to remain, each "folder" is essentially a mini-website. Maybe I just need to use filestore instead.

Comment: Firestore won't provide you that level of authorization. The only idea I have is to implement your own authorization in a database, keep that in a session with the client, and keep track of where in your tiered mini-websites the user has access. This is a very common thing to do in PHP, so you will be able to find lots of examples on Google. This might sound complicated but it really is not. The problem I see is how do you authorize Google Cloud Storage without using either public or signed urls and without funneling that data thru your webserver.

Comment: I was thinking filestore https://cloud.google.com/filestore/ since it’s just nfs. But I agree with you and probably the best the solution is what you outlined. These mini websites are really just converted PowerPoint slides - but the reality from a technical perspective it’s a mini website. From the user perspective it’s a slideshow so shouldn’t be hard. I appreciate the input, it’s nice when you can bounce ideas off someone. I’ll leave it up for one more day but then I’ll just mark your solution correct if no one has some magical solution by then. I appreciate the responses and guidance.

Comment: Sorry about Firestore versus Filestore. One little letter and a very different service. Filestore won't help you either as the access is via your instance which of course has access already (short of implementing IAM again).